# @import in index.css not working with rollup

Tags: css, reactjs, rollup, postcss

I'm currently trying to do a react component library with react and rollup.
It's working pretty fine, i can import scss or css files my reacts components.
But when I try to import in my `index.css` file externals files they are still imported when I build with rollup, but there is no associated files to this import in the dist folder.

this is my rollup.config.js file

```js
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },  
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({
        tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
        exclude: ["**/src/stories/**", "**/*.stories.tsx"],
      }),
      postcss({
        extract: true
      }),
      terser(),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: [/\.css$/, /\.scss$/],
  },
];
```

my `index.ts`

```js
import "./index.css"
export * from "./components"
```

my `index.css`

```css
@import './toto.css'
```

`toto.css`

```css
.toto {
    color: aquamarine;
}
```

[image]
as you can see the `toto.css` file is imported but nowhere in the folder generated i can find the file or its css properties.

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i found out where was the problem, i just forgot to add 'postcss-import': {} in my postcss config.jsfile

It solves the issue.